# Is it possible to "save" a variable value in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a website where I want the client to be able to make their site go live by setting `var live = true;`, and then setting webpages to display if it is true. I don't want to save the `live` variable in a database (a collection solely for that would not make sense). Is there a way to assign a permanent value to the variable in NodeJS?

Comment: Where are you saving everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use environment variables. When starting the NodeJs service, you can pass variables like this,

```
LIVE=true node server.js
```

Then access it from the app from anywhere like this,

```
var live = process.env.LIVE
```

**However**, I would recommend using environment specific configuration files for your purpose. By doing so, you can change the LIVE variable based on the execution environment (QA, DEV, STAGING, PRODUCTION, etc)

You can define a json file with the configurations you need,

```
{
    "LIVE": true,
    // More variables can be defined here
}
```

And store the files in an absolute path(not in the local repo), like `/usr/local/my_configs/` or `/etc/my_confs/`.

Then `import` or `require` the config files similar to how you would require a `.js` file.

like this,

```
var my_config = require('/etc/my_confs/my_conf.json');
const LIVE = my_config.LIVE;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will probably use process.env variables instead of JSON, because the user needs to change it from a website GUI.

Comment: @IsaacKrementsov Sounds to me that you shouldn't be using either of the solutions then. If that variable is changed by a GUI, your best bet will be to save it in either the application state or use a separate service like a database or at least a text file.

Comment: Why wouldn't I just use process.env.LIVE = user_value_here?

Comment: It's like using a shaving blade to cut vegetables. While it may still work, the intention is different. process.env variables are supposed to be used to define the execution environment. They shouldn't be changed by users, specially during the run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't exactly save it, but read from your environment file (or) environment variables. Like `.env`.

To change the variable, you must configure the environment variables.

.env(Local):

```
LIVE=TRUE
```

In the cloud, you would have GUI settings, where you can configure the variables.

Then you can simply set the variable to:

```
var live = process.env.LIVE;
```

Ask your client to manually set the variable. Mostly you have to restrict their accessibility

Answer (score 0):

You can use YAML module in nodejs.

```
default:
  server:
    port: 6379                # server port
    live: true                # option for live
```

> You can read these values and write on these values. it is faster and
>   safe method and kind of small database which is you want

https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-config

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is going to be changing for different users have it store in a JSON file against user id. Consider [DiskDb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diskdb) JSON file but can be used as Query.

Answer (score 0):

you can app it to process variable like this :

```
process.live = true  ;
```

then you can access it in anywhere in system , but if you run two system you will can change process.live value from the other system becouse process object save